# In laravel hasmany relationship data is not displayed/fetched straight after creating them

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have a store method where it saves or update adult details for an advice file.

Relationships:

```
An AdviceFile hasMany Adult
An Adult belongsTo an AdviceFile
```

I think my method is straightforward (might be wrong), but at the end when I try to fetch `adults` belonging to the `adviceFile` it doesn’t fetch any.

Any idea why this may happen?

Here is my `store` method

```
public function store(AdviceFile $adviceFile, AdultDataRequest $request)
    {
        $requestData = $request->data;

        foreach ($requestData as $adultDetails) {
            if (isset($adultDetails["id"])) {
                // Update the record
                $keysToExclude = [
                    'id', 'advice_file_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'
                ];
                $data = array_except($adultDetails, $keysToExclude);
                $adult = Adult::find($adultDetails["id"]);
                $adult->data = $data;
                $adult->save();
            } else {
                // Create record
                Adult::create([
                    'advice_file_id' => $adviceFile->id,
                    'data' => $adultDetails
                ]);
            }
        }
        //This is where I get an empty response, even though there is data in db
        return AdultResource::collection($adviceFile->adults); 
    }
```

Comment: I thought you said `adult` (singular) belongs to `adviceFile`? because I see you're referring to `$adviceFile->adults` (plural). Also is there a method name that matches `adult` or as you use it `adults` in your `AdviceFile` model?

Comment: you should post your AdviceFile and Adult Models .but..maybe...In  foreach $adviceFile->adult()->associate($adult);  where $adult is what you update or save inside foreach....

Comment: @koalaok We won't be able to use associate method with a hasMany relationships.. Posted solution below

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to load the relation before the return statement:

```
$adults = $adviceFile->adults()->get();
return AdultResource::collection($adults);
```

Credits to @brunodevel and @hailwood from `larachat`

```
// Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes

public function getRelationValue($key)
    {
        // If the key already exists in the relationships array, it just means the
        // relationship has already been loaded, so we'll just return it out of
        // here because there is no need to query within the relations twice.
        if ($this->relationLoaded($key)) {
            return $this->relations[$key];
        }
    ...
}
```